# WMI Query SID to User

Tags: wmi, wmi-query

I'm looking for a simple WQL query that can convert an Windows user SID to a username.

There are multiple methods that show this being done through wmic or powershell, I am using a python module which is capable of running WQL queries against some local namespace - and would just need a query.

I am using WBEMTest for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Select * FROM win32_accountSID